# PHP HTML geolocation coordinates

Tags: php, javascript, html

How can I get coordinates in a html field, so I can make post-back and save the data **using geolocation feature from HTML5?**

I'm using php as back-end language. Also I'm very new in the usage of javascript, some baby steps would be appreciated.

Comment: so you want help with the geolocation or setting a form field value?

Comment: @Ben sorry I need to get the coordinates of the map to a form field...so you could say I need to link them so that my submit returns the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [getElementByItd](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-getelementbyid.php) function to set the value of a field from javascript.

Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('ID_OF_HTML_FIELD').value = THE_VALUE_YOU_WANT_TO_SET
```

Edit: also [here](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-started-html5-geolocation)'s a tutorial on geolocation with html5 in case you need help with that.

Comment: that only partly answers the vague question (not blaming you :)